# A game is played. Probability

Tags: probability

A game is played as follows: A random number $X$ is chosen uniformly from $[0,
1]$. Then a sequence $Y_1, Y_2,\ldots$ of random numbers is chosen independently
and uniformly from $[0, 1]$. The game ends the first time that $Y_i > X$. You are
then paid $(i-1)$ dollars. What is a fair entrance fee for this game?

Comment: (i1) dollars? Do you mean (i-1) dollars?

Comment: Every time Y is smaller than x you receive a dollar.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Z$ represent the payment. Then
$$\Bbb{P}(Z = k|X = x) = \Bbb{P}(Y_1 \le x, Y_2 \le x, \ldots , Y_k \le x, Y_{k+1} > x)
= x^k(1 − x) .$$
Therefore,
$$\Bbb{P}(Z = k) = \int_0^1 x^k(1 − x)\operatorname{d}x=\left[\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}-\frac{x^{k+2}}{k+2}\right]_0^1=\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2}=\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}.$$

Thus,
$$\Bbb{E}(Z) =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k\Bbb{P}(Z = k)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k}{(k+1)(k+2)},$$
which diverges.

Thus, you should be willing to pay any amount to play this game.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  If I told you $X$, can you calculate the value $V(X)$? Then since $X$ is selected uniformly, the overall value is $\int_0^1V(X)\ dX$